# Artificially increasing training data for regression by Random Forest and Neural Networks

Tags: r, machine-learning, neural-network, regression, random-forest

We are trying to predict sales quantity based on their attribute values .We have around 8000 records of data for training .Is it correct to increase training data by adding small variations to sales quantity for same 8000 records ?
I want to prepare new training set with 24000(3*8000) records with sales quantity + or - 0.1 for those 8000 records

Ex:like original data sales quantity=2  then new data will have 2,2.1 and 1.9 for same item.

Comment: This is a methodology question better posted on crossValidated or on datascience.stackexchange.com. I'd recommend that you remove the question from here and ask on one of those sites.

Comment: This questions is more appropriately asked in the DataScience or CrossValidated stacks because it is about conceptual computing more than code. That having been said, if I am understanding you right, you are asking if you should alter the predictors slightly and create more data to try to build a more robust predictor. My answer would be no! You would be training based on noise which will not build a better model. Bootstrapping from your current data is a better method, and it is the foundation of random forests sampling method.

Answer (score 0):

The usefulness of variation depends on the scalar quantity of the attribute. For example, if your feature range is (0-100) adding +/- 0.1 is useless. If it is (0 < x < +1, just an example), then yes, the variations can make a good difference.

I think a better way would be to normalize your data (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.normalize.html) then add the variations.

If you have categorical data, you can convert them to dummy variables if needed (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html).

Answer (score 0):

Bad idea! Because intuitively it will not really help. It might just, unnecessarily, overfit the Random forest or NN model.